# Verbb Wishlist plugin see if item is in specific list

Tags: plugins

Looking at the docs, it says to check if an item is in wishlist using the below code:

```
{% set compare = craft.wishlist.item(entry.id) %}
{% if compare.inList %}
    <a class="" href="{{ compare.addUrl() }}&fields[linkTo]={{ entry.url }}&listTypeHandle=compare">Remove from Compare</a>
{% else %}
    <a class="" href="{{ compare.removeUrl() }}&fields[linkTo]={{ entry.url }}&listTypeHandle=compare">Compare</a>
{% endif %}
```

I want to do the above but tell it what list to look in i.e craft.wishlist.type('compare').item(entry.id)

I cannot see how on earth to do this. I have multiple lists that an entry could be in, so need to specify.

Any help would be very gratefully received!!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a list type handle in the query like this:

```
{% set compare = craft.wishlist.item(entry.id, null, 'compare') %}
```

I had to look at the [source code](https://github.com/verbb/wishlist/blob/craft-3/src/variables/WishlistVariable.php) for the `craft.wishlist` variable to confirm what that's doing, though! The [Wishlist docs on checking if an item is in a list](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/wishlist/docs/template-guides/managing-items#check-if-in-list) aren't super-clear on this, but passing the list type handle in the query will fetch the *first* list that matches that handle for the current user. If you have multiple lists for that list type, only the first one that the query returns will be checked for the item.

Comment: I think this searches through all items of all users. Not sure if you want that.